# How to disable the camera sound on a Huawei G525?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, silent-mode, huawei, camera-sound

I have a Huawei G525 (Android 4.2 jelly bean). The Camera makes a sound when taking photos even when it's in silent mode. How do I disable the shutter sound altogether?

Comment: I'm not English, so feel free to correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the settings inside the camera app there should be one to change/disable camera sounds. If there's no such option, I'm afraid the only alternative you have is to try alternative 3rd part camera apps.